# Accessing bpy.context gives a '_RestrictContext' warning, how to fix this?

Tags: add-on, sculpting

I got this error message when I try to enable my addon.

```
dataBrush = bpy.context.blend_data.brushes

AttributeError:'_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'blend_data'
```

Please some help

[image: Error in enablling addon]

I am working on an dynamic palette for sculpt brushes
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: don't access blendfile data when an add-on loads.

---

This is an intentional limitation with add-on loading which was added because it caused so many errors with inexperienced developers not properly understanding how data should be accessed, in practice it's almost **never what you really want**, and if for some obscure reason it is, you better not do it in an add-on (just run a script directly).

The kind of bug this caused was:

- Add-on loads, sets the active scene. eg: `scene = bpy.context.scene`
- User changes active scene or loads another blend file.
- User tries to use the add-on, which starts using the previous scene.

Enabling an add-on should always give the same results no matter what Blend file you have open.

Instead, your tools should read from the context when they are activated by the user.

Comment: -"dataBrush = bpy.data.brushes "-
give me ~ the same error message:

AttributeError:'_restrictContext' object has no attribute 'brushes'

Comment: Yep, this is working as its intended. Whatever you want to do with the brushes, add this into code thats access from an operator, panel, menu etc... The current open blend file shouldn't influence an add-ons startup which should never depend on the currently open file, otherwise loading another blend file may make the addon fail.

Comment: ideasman42♦ I just need the current list of brushes to run the script, how can I make this happen ?

Comment: You can't do this in an addon (while the addon initializes), but interested to know what you are attempting.

Comment: @IssanouKamardineIK You can read `bpy.data.brushes` in your panel's `draw()` method, but you shouldn't need it when you are registering your addon.

Comment: nice, I found a way to run the script by using an operator to call a second file.
Thank you guys :)

Comment: @ideasman42 nice explanation of WHY it had been disabled in the end. Makes perfect sense to me now.