# How can I add custom icon for my operators in a specific addon?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

According to [**this**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32335/how-to-implement-custom-icons-for-my-script-addon) question and [**this**](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.82a/bpy.utils.previews.html) example I am trying to **add** some **custom icons** to my addon's **operators**. But I have an "issue".

In both examples, functions `draw`, `register` and `unregister` are in the same file. In my case, `register` and `unregister` functions located into my `__init__.py` file and looks totally different and the `draw` function located into an other file I have create by the name `fu3dm_main.py`. Can anyone help me on how I'll apply this example in my case?

Here is how my `__init__.py` file looks:

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Blah blah blah",
    "author" : "Simonetos The Greek <simonetos.the.greek@gmail.com>",
    "description" : "Blah blah blah",
    "blender" : (2, 90, 1),
    "version" : (1, 0, 0),
    "location" : "View3D",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Generic"
}

import bpy
from . fu3dm      import *
from . fu3dm_main import *

ops = fu3dm.ops

classes = (
    fu3dm.ops.view.front,
    fu3dm.ops.view.back,
    fu3dm.ops.view.right,
    fu3dm.ops.view.left,
    fu3dm.ops.view.top,
    fu3dm.ops.view.bottom,
    fu3dm.ops.preferences.model,
    fu3dm_main.panel
)

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
```

And here is how my `fu3dm_main.py` file looks:

```
import bpy
from . fu3dm import *

class fu3dm_main():
    """Main class"""

    class panel(bpy.types.Panel):
        """Main panel class"""

        bl_idname = "fu3dm.main_PT_Panel"
        bl_label = "Blah blah blah"
        bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
        bl_region_type = "UI"
        bl_category = "FU3DM"

        @classmethod
        def poll(cls, context):
            return bpy.data.collections.get("FU3DM v20.0")

        def draw(self, context):
                layout = self.layout
            #   ┌────────┐
            #   │ Box #1 │
            #   └┬───────┘
                box1 = layout.box()
                box1_col1 = box1.column()

                box1_row1 = box1_col1.split()
                box1_row1.label(text="Preferences:")
                box1_row1.operator("fu3dm.model_prefs")
            #   ┌┴────┐
            #   │ End │
            #   └─────┘
```

Comment: Personally I go for methods outlined here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158775/having-trouble-creating-an-addon-with-multiple-modules and again https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/183817/15543 in which case can edit a module without need to edit module init.  Please also see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_best_practice.html re class names.  Why the double up module and class names `fu3dm_main.fu3dm_main`?  Lastly using `from foo import *` is rarely recommended.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41565/loading-icons-into-custom-addon

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you very much for these useful links, I have to study them for sure!!! The `from foo import *` it's just temporary, I'll fix it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution from this attached file [here](https://developer.blender.org/T64628), and here is a code example...

```
import os

import bpy
import bpy.utils.previews
from bpy.types import Panel


preview_collections = {}
# If you work with a simple script.
dir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
# If you work with an addon.
# dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")

pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()

for entry in os.scandir(dir):
    if entry.name.endswith(".png"):
        name = os.path.splitext(entry.name)[0]
        pcoll.load(name.upper(), entry.path, "IMAGE")


class VIEW3D_PT_test(Panel):
    bl_label = "TEST"
    bl_category = "TEST"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        layout.prop(scene, "use_gravity", text="Enable Layout")

        col = layout.column()
        col.enabled = scene.use_gravity
        col.operator("object.duplicate_move", text="Custom Icon", icon_value=pcoll["ICON"].icon_id)
        col.operator("object.duplicate_move", text="Built-in Icon", icon="OUTPUT")


bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_test)
```

Just **note**, that If you work on an **addon**, the `dir` should be like this `dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")` and icons should be saved in `.png` format into folder `icons` into the same place where your `.py` file is.

And if you work on a **simple script**, `dir` should be like this `dir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)` and icons should be into the same place where your `.py` and `.blend` file is.