# Installing custom Pie Menu, Restricted Context Error

Tags: scripting, add-on, pie-menu

I am having issues creating a custom "Add Mesh" pie menu, Ive made a script, sampling from a number of different sources of code, that functions well enough from the text editor, However when i try to install it as an addon and enable it i get this error.

[image]

Which through reading a number of posts I believe I understand the "why" of why its happening, but my limited Python knowledge is hindering my ability to fix it. I believe the issue comes up at line 201 or so where i am trying to create a custom operator to assign different meshes with custom properties. At least thats what i understand it to be.

Ive tried altering the order of the class-list to change registration order, creating a class in itself for assigning the "type= bpy.props etc" attribute and registering that outside of the normal class list. Ive tried throwing an @classmethod or two in there (like i REALLY know what that's doing) but this is all mostly flailing in the dark and trying stuff i find in other stackexchange answers but nothing so far is helping.

I would greatly appreciate any help offered! Thank you in advance for your time.

My Script
https://pastebin.com/t8DfUscG

Solutions I have tried, to the extent of my knowledge.
This one being the main devlog post detailing the error, Which i cant figure how to use in my own script, but am sure would fix the issue.

https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes/#Restricted_Context

As well as these other ones, as well as several other minor attempts.

[Accessing bpy.context gives a '_RestrictContext' warning, how to fix this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24415/accessing-bpy-context-gives-a-restrictcontext-warning-how-to-fix-this)

[Application addon using bpy.data.scenes causes: AttributeError: '_RestrictData' object has no attribute 'scenes'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154431/application-addon-using-bpy-data-scenes-causes-attributeerror-restrictdata)

Comment: The issue is that you call the operator right away at the bottom of your script. Move that inside of the `if __name__ == "__main__":` and you won't get an error when installing. If you want to use it as an add-on you probably want to create a shortcut to the pie menu or add another operator which allows you to call the pie menu.

Comment: Hi. Please include the code in the question body itself. If necessary, reduce the code to a smaller sample that still shows the issue.

Comment: @RobertGützkow that did the trick! thank you I really appreciate it.