# Add-On Dev: Per-File Initialization (Issues Enabling Add-on After File Load)

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I've noticed a lot of add-on code using the `load_post` handler to serve as a sort of startup event. This makes a lot of sense, because many elements do not exist before that moment, and most add-ons need to associate with them.

But what about when an add-on is activated after the blend file is loaded? The normal startup sequence seems to be `load_pre, addon.register, load_post`, which allows us to sync with the file contents. But how do we detect when `load_post` happens before our add-on is registered?

I've tried accessing `bpy.data.*` and `bpy.context.*`, to try to detect any differences, but they are both restricted at normal startup. Is there a safe way to ask the environment if any scenes exist?

Edit: Just want to sum my problem up as a really simple question: How do I initialize add-on states that need to look at scene elements?

Comment: Hi. If you can explain the specific situation that makes you think you need to do this, it might help.

Comment: Just any situation where you need to look at the scene at startup would encounter the issue. For example, if an add-on actively manipulates lights, I'm assuming it would need to detect the existence of lights before it starts manipulating them. I may have explained it poorly, but I'm just trying to detect weather or not a scene already exists when my add-on starts. In my specific situation, I'm wanting to build a hierarchy table. I also have certain routines that shouldn't run unless certain scene elements are present.

Comment: After reading about it, it looks like they limited access to the scene during registration to help protect developers from themselves. But any add-on that makes use of `load_post` is likely to break when activated after loading a file. Whatever it does in that function will fail to happen until a new file is loaded.

Comment: You're having a hard time working around the restriction, because you're not supposed to do that. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24415/accessing-bpy-context-gives-a-restrictcontext-warning-how-to-fix-this

Comment: I actually mixed myself up on the restriction thing. My problem is wanting to initialize add-on states that rely on scene objects. I was trying to solve it by checking for a valid scene on startup. But I didn't realize I was doing that check inside of register. So I confused the restriction error with an invalid scene. If anyone has the add-on **io_scene_valvesource**, that is an example of an add-on that used a hack to fix this problem. They register their post-loading event function as `load_post` **and** `depsgraph_update_post`, then delete the depsgraph version after it gets called.

Comment: It's currently in the middle of the night so I can't the add-on you're referring to. The issue with this approach is that you are checking a state that may not be valid anymore once you actually execute an operator later on. Which is precisely the reason why the restriction were imposed in the first place. Say you want to check if scene had a certain property and your test when loading the add-on is positive. Now before any operator is executed the user switches the scene. Now your check was made on the wrong scene and your state is invalid.

Comment: All the use cases you've described should not be handled when loading the add-on. Either calculate the state on the fly when the operator is executed or use something like a handler for `depsgraph_update_post` to continuously update the state whenever something relevant in the project changes.

Comment: I understand your point. You're saying the add-on the should update on the fly to make sure scene-specific information is still accurate. But even those add-ons would want to start up with accurate information. They have no reliable constructor-like event where scene data is available. And there are a lot of situations where a continuous update would not make sense. What if an add-on adds something to each project exactly one time? Like a global object, hidden global states, or a singleton into `bpy.data.scenes[0]`, etc. Changing scenes would not cause any issues with these.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't be trying to argue any points with my limited experience with this. My purpose was to find a safe way to initialize scene-related states at startup, but I think that question has been answered. It doesn't look like its possible without some type event hack. Either way, I appreciate the advice.

Comment: No problem, having a discussion about these things is good because it allows everybody to learn. We can be wrong too, sometimes.

Comment: BTW make sure you tag people with e.g. @rjg otherwise they don't get notified that you left a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add-ons *can* do per-file initialisation, *if* the add-on has some kind of panel in the UI somewhere.

You may notice various panels in Blender's UI have checkboxes next to the panel title. This is can be because they don't want to be active unless specifically turned on, but it can also be because they want to do some setup before being used:

[image]

This can be achieved in your own add-on by adding a `draw_header` function into the class that defines your panel:

```
def draw_header(self, context):

    self.layout.prop(context.scene, "addon_panel_enabled", text="")
```

The `draw_header` displays a boolean which I created and registered in the `register` function of the add-on:

```
bpy.types.Scene.addon_panel_enabled = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False, update=initialiseAddon)
```

The property has an `update` function called `initialiseAddon` which runs when the boolean is changed. It is in `initialiseAddon` that you can run your setup code.

Be aware, however, that this will run when the header checkbox is enabled *and* disabled. You could of course include code to make sure it only runs once by checking if the header boolean is `true` (the update function seems to be run *after* the value has been set):

```
def initialiseAddon(self, context):
    if context.scene.addon_panel_enabled:
        print("Only runs when enabling the checkbox")
```

Or just make another property which stores whether initialisation has been done or inspect your own data.

If you *don't* have a panel, then you should do initialisation in your operator when it first runs and again, have a scene property that stores whether setup has been done or not.

Full code (based on the *UI Panel Simple* template that comes with Blender):

```
import bpy

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw_header(self, context):

        self.layout.prop(context.scene, "addon_panel_enabled", text="")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")

def initialiseAddon(self, context):
    #Per file initialisation code here
    if context.scene.addon_panel_enabled == True:
        print("Only runs when enabling the checkbox")

def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.addon_panel_enabled = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False, update=initialiseAddon)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.addon_panel_enabled

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: That is one of the right ways to accomplish the goal.

Comment: Yeah, any type of user event that indicates the user wants to use the add-on would be a good place to initialize. The best place for a panel add-on would be when the user expands the panel itself, but there's unfortunately no event for that.