# v2.79 - Exported .py errors

Tags: python

i tried to export my .py and want to upload it as addon.

the script works perfect, but when i try to import it as addon i get these errors:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access the scene before the add-on is registered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing bpy.context gives a '\_RestrictContext' warning, how to fix this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24415/accessing-bpy-context-gives-a-restrictcontext-warning-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: Under the import bpy line igot directly this scene=Context.scene.     Is this wrong? Becs when i delete it my script isnt working

Comment: Yes that is wrong, if you're trying to develop an add-on. Sounds like you've written a regular Python script, not a Blender add-on

Comment: Yep, is it hard to make a script to an addon?

Comment: Hard to answer, depends on your experience with python and programming. The manual has a chapter about add-on development: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html If you're stuck somewhere and you don't find an existing answer to your problem just ask a new question about it.